# selectSingleNode возвращает null (E_FAIL)

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++

Работаю на VS2015 Community Edition (так же пробовал этот код и на VS2008 Professional Edition). Функция selectSingleNode() возвращает null (E_FAIL).

Для работы с xml создал класс CXmlDocument

```
// XmlDocument.h
class CXmlDocument
{
public:
    CXmlDocument( const CStringW& szXml );
    CStringW GetNodeText( const CStringW& szXPath ) const;

private:
    CComPtr< MSXML::IXMLDOMDocument > m_Document;
};

// XmlDocument.cpp
CXmlDocument::CXmlDocument( const CStringW& szXml )
{
    if ( m_Document.CoCreateInstance( MSXML::CLSID_DOMDocument60 ) != S_OK )
    {
        return;
    }

    m_Document->put_validateOnParse( VARIANT_FALSE );

    VARIANT_BOOL bIsSuccessful;
    m_Document->loadXML( CComBSTR( szXml ), &bIsSuccessful );
}

CStringW CXmlDocument::GetNodeText( const CStringW& szXPath ) const
{
    CStringW szResult;

    if ( m_Document )
    {
        CComPtr< MSXML::IXMLDOMNode > node;
        if ( m_Document->selectSingleNode( CComBSTR( szXPath ), &node ) == S_OK && node )
        {
            CComBSTR bstrText;
            node->get_text( &bstrText );
            szResult = bstrText;
        }
    }

    return szResult;
}
```

Основной код приложения:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "XmlDocument.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
const CStringW testXml =

        L"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
        L"<d:propfind xmlns:d=\"DAV:\">"
        L"Hello"
        L"</d:propfind>";

    const CXmlDocument document(testXml);
    CStringW result = document.GetNodeText(L"/d:propfind");
    printf("Result: %S\n", result);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

И подключаемые заголовки:

```
// stdafx.h
#ifndef STRICT
#define STRICT
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
#define _ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE
#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlctl.h>
#include <ATLComTime.h>
#include <atlcoll.h>
#include <atlfile.h>
#include <atlsafe.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <atlutil.h>

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <assert.h>

using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
using std::tr1::weak_ptr;

using namespace ATL;

#import <msxml6.dll> rename_namespace("MSXML"), named_guids, no_auto_exclude, raw_interfaces_only
using namespace MSXML;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при использовании метода GetNodeText() возвращается пустая строка. Дебаг показал, что проблема кроется в использовании функции selectSingleNode(). После вызова она возвращает E_FAIL и ничего не записывает в node. Однако, если убрать namespace из testXml и из запроса XPath, то приложение работает нормально и выводится строка Hello. Поиск по гуглу разумных ответов не дал как задать пространство имен в этом случае. Или же, причина в чем-то другом?

Comment: это из-за того что у выбираемого тега  **namespace** задан.

Comment: @nick_n_a , если делать запрос без указания **namespace** то функция возвращает E_FALSE. Это эквивалентно тому, что указанная нода не найдена.

Comment: метод get_namespaceURI() для testXml возвращает S_FALSE, что говорит о том, что в xml документе не установлено пространство имен. То есть, почему-то библиотека msxml6.dll не видит строчку, содержащую **xmlns:d="DAV:"**